# Issue in View Blob PDF in Mobile Web Browser using Angular

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular

**strong text**Kindly help me out!!

Im using angular 13, trying to convert the array buffer to blob and viewing the blob data in iframe it perfectly opens in Web Browser but in mobile web browser shows error while blob conversion

```
error : <html><body><!-- no enabled plugin supports this MIME type --></body></html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vNnp.jpg)
in mobile web browser it display like this but when i click open nothing happens

```
  let file = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: result.file.type });
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);  
          this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileURL) 


    <iframe *ngIf="url" [src]="url" allow='autoplay' width="100%" height="800" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: cant understand what you trying to say @K J

Comment: What is the error you're getting?